# Drawing using QPainter periodically

Tags: c++, qt

I'm attempting to create a simple animation in Qt through QPainter, currently i've been able to draw in my window, but i'm unable to figure out how i could draw the same thing periodically.

Here's my current code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
QApplication a (argc, argv);
QLabel l;
Qpicture pi;
Qpainter p(&pi);
Qpen pen;
/*
Some ellipses and lines using p.drawLine and p.drawEllipse
*/
p.end();
l.setPicture(pi);
l.show();

return a.exec();
```

I've tried creating a thread, but i can't create a QApplication outside of main and if i try to give my painter, label, picture and pen to a thread, then it won't compile as they are private:

```
void PrintThread ( QLabel * l, QPicture * pi, Qpainter * p, QPen * pen){
    /*
    print lines and ellipses
    */
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
QApplication a (argc, argv);
    QLabel l;
    Qpicture pi;
    Qpainter p(&pi);
    Qpen pen;
std::thread doPaint (PrintThread, l, pi, p, pen);
doPaint.join();
```

How would a sample code that draws anything (lines/ellipses) using Qpainter every X milliseconds look like?

Comment: You can use a QTimer and call the update function every time the timer is elapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually worked out on a **clean** solution, adding support for reading keypresses aswell:

main.cpp

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QApplication>
#include "screen.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    screen Screen;

    // size of your choice
    Screen.setFixedSize(1024,576);

    Screen.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

screen.h

```
#ifndef SCREEN_H
#define SCREEN_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>

class screen : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    screen();
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *);
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *);
public slots:
    void tick();
};

#endif // SCREEN_H
```

screen.cpp

```
#include "screen.h"

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QTimer>

QPen pen;
QPicture pic;
QPainter p;

screen::screen(){

    QTimer * timer = new QTimer();
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(tick()));

    timer->start(16);
}
void screen::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    // event for key pressed
}

void screen::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    // event for key released
}

void screen::tick(){
    p.begin(&pic);

    // start draw



    // finish draw

    p.end();
    this->setPicture(pic);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's this crazy disease going on, where people automatically associate periodic/timed task with multithreading. You need nothing of the sort - just use a timer:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/picture-async-44201102
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtConcurrent>

class PictureSource : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   QPicture draw() {
      QPicture pic;
      QPainter p(&pic);
      p.rotate(QTime::currentTime().msec()*360./1000.);
      p.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50);
      pic.setBoundingRect({-50, -50, 100, 100});
      emit pictureChanged(pic);
      return pic;
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void pictureChanged(const QPicture &);
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QPicture)

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   qRegisterMetaType<QPicture>();
   QLabel label;
   PictureSource source;
   QObject::connect(&source, &PictureSource::pictureChanged,
                    &label, &QLabel::setPicture);
   source.draw();
   label.show();
   QTimer timer;
   timer.start(50); // every 50 ms
   QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &source, &PictureSource::draw);
   return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Now - if you think you need to - you can do the drawing in a worker thread from the thread pool. Replace the connection with:

```
  QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&source]{
    auto pool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();
    QtConcurrent::run(pool, [&source]{ source.draw(); });
  });
```

Ensure that `draw()` is thread-safe, or that you otherwise don't modify the `source` object concurrently from the main thread without proper synchronization.

Comment: Yep, apparently i had to remove mainwindow.ui (even tho i wasn't using it) from my project as it wouldn't find main.moc otherwise (altho i'm unsure as to why it does right now).

Comment: You had a stale build folder. When unsure whether the code or the project or the build is at fault, delete the build and rebuild the project **first**. You can add `mainwindow.ui` to this project and it will work just fine. Also when posting about errors, it helps to post actual errors with actual code you're building, and almost by definition you're wasting time if you don't try a fresh build first (i.e. without the old build folder present).